# Where does ${basedir} variable in pom.xml directs to?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Where does `${basedir}` directs to? Does this variable directs to path where pom.xml file is in?

Comment: Is this actually a maven question?

Comment: @JeremyP Are you really asking this? This variable is commonly used  in pom.xml and build.xml files for plug-ins to give a path. I am just wondering where exactly it directs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation can be read in here:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Available_Variables

As per description:
"The directory that the current project resides in."